# React Hook - Use effect on component unmount only, not when dependency updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build an input component using React Hooks that hits a remote server to save an updated value on component unmount only.

The remote server call is expensive, so I do not want to hit the server every time the input updates.

When I use the cleanup hook in `useEffect`, I am required to include the input value in the effect dependency array, which makes the remote API call execute on each update of the  input value. If I don't include the input value in the effect dependency array, the updated input value is never saved.

Here is a code sandbox that shows the problem and explains the expected outcome: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-meadow-nzkyv

Is it possible to accomplish this using React hooks? I know it defies parts of the paradigm of hooks, but surely this is a common-enough use case that it should be possible.

Comment: You could [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the function that sends the value with a generous wait interval value and call that debounced function in your hook with the input value as dependency. That way the update request wouldn't be sent to your backend on every single keystroke. Make sure to declare the debounced function only once. If possible outside your function component, or via `useCallback` inside the component.

Comment: @tiguchi – I thought about that and am still considering it. My fear with using debounce is that if they force the component to unmount (ie closing a modal with the form), the state may not be saved. So, I either need to have a pretty tiny wait interval, or I still need a solution to the question :(

Comment: I think this would only be a problem if the user deliberately reloads or leaves the page before the timeout triggers the API call. React JS apps are usually modeled as SPAs, so even browser URL changes would not cause timeouts or other global state to get lost. However, you could create something like an API singleton service that queues those API requests, processes them in a "debounced" manner, and makes sure that all remaining queued requests get processed when the current page gets unloaded  (via refresh or by leaving the site)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to capture the changing value of your text, then you can reference it in another `useEffect` hook to save the text:

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
const textRef = React.useRef(text);

React.useEffect( () => {
  textRef.current = text;    
}, [text])

React.useEffect( () => {
  return () => doSomething(textRef.current)
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response – I considered this approach as well. I was hoping to keep using `useState` since I do want to re-render based on the update of the input state

Comment: this approach work with the state you manage
I updated the answer to show this more explicitly

Comment: I see! This makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`thedude`'s approach is right. Tweaked it a bit, for this particular usecase as `input` ref is always same :

```
function SavedInput() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      save(inputEl.current.value);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputEl} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

By this way you'll avoid re-render as you are not setting any state.